# Imports (using) in Microsoft Visual studio doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want load image to my program, but `usings` doens't work. Why?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace myProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Image image1 = Image.FromFile("c:\\Photo1.jpg");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to the proper DLL?

Comment: What using are you trying to import? Do you receive an error?

Comment: How do you notice that it is not working? Please post that as well..

Comment: Error is: The name "IMAGE" doesn't exist in current context. No i not add reference to DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you dont add references. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx) you can read how to do in in Visual Studio. What DLL you need to certain namespace, you can check on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/)

Comment: It is always good to lay out the fundamentals that are described in your links in your answer. Links go dead quickly (even though MSDN will probably stick around) and then your answer is useless for future readers.